# TSQL Compare tables based on multiple rows same column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i will try and be as clear as possible on this one, as i have no idea what to do next and would love a kick in the right direction.

Im trying to compare the values within 2 tables. The tables look like this:

Table1:

[image: Table1]

Table2

[image: Table2]

```
    INSERT INTO #table1 ([elementName], [elementValue])
VALUES 
('t1','Project'),
('p1','test1'),
('n1','value1'),

('t2','Project'),
('p2','test2'),
('n2','value2'),

('t3','Project'),
('p3','test3'),
('n3','value3'),

('t4',''),
('p4',''),
('n4',''),

('t5',''),
('p5',''),
('n5','')


INSERT INTO #table2 ([elementName], [elementValue])
VALUES 
('t1','Project'),
('p1',''),
('n1',''),

('t2','Project'),
('p2','test3'),
('n2','value123'),

('t3','Project'),
('p3',''),
('n3',''),

('t4','Package'),
('p4',''),
('n4',''),

('t5','Project'),
('p5','Testtest'),
('n5','valuevalue')
```

I used this code to fill the testtables. Normally this is an automated process, and the tables are filled from an XML string.

Furthermore, the numbers in the element name are considered "groups" meaning T1 P1 and N1 are together.

I would like to compare T1 and P1 etc from Table1 to any combination of T and P from table2
If they match, i would like to overwrite the value of Table 1 N1 with the value of the matched N on table 2. (in the example, table1 N3 would be replaced with table2 N2

Besides that i also want to keep every group in table 1 that is not in table 2
but also add every group that is in table 2 but not in table 1 on one of the blank spots.

Last but not least, if the T value is filled, but P value is empty, it does not have to overwrite/change anything in table1.

The expected result would be this:

Table1:

[image]

i made the changes bold.

I dont really have an idea on where to start on this. Ive tried functions as except and intersect, but did not get even close to what i would like to see.

Comment: Are you using [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server] here? The fact that you use brackets (`[]`) to delimit identify suggests the latter.

Comment: sql-server yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
with t1 as (
  select * from (values
  ('t1','Project'),
  ('p1','test1'),
  ('n1','value1'),

  ('t2','Project'),
  ('p2','test2'),
  ('n2','value2'),

  ('t3','Project'),
  ('p3','test3'),
  ('n3','value3'),

  ('t4',''),
  ('p4',''),
  ('n4',''),

  ('t5',''),
  ('p5',''),
  ('n5','')
  ) v([elementName], [elementValue])
),
t2 as (
  select * from (values
  ('t1','Project'),
  ('p1',''),
  ('n1',''),

  ('t2','Project'),
  ('p2','test3'),
  ('n2','value123'),

  ('t3','Project'),
  ('p3',''),
  ('n3',''),

  ('t4','Package'),
  ('p4',''),
  ('n4',''),

  ('t5','Project'),
  ('p5','Testtest'),
  ('n5','valuevalue')
  ) v([elementName], [elementValue])
),
pivoted_t1 as (
  select *
  from
    (select left([elementName], 1) letter, right([elementName], len([elementName]) - 1) number, [elementValue] as value from t1) t1
    pivot(min(value) for letter in ([t], [p], [n])) pvt1
),
pivoted_t2 as (
  select *
  from
    (select left([elementName], 1) letter, right([elementName], len([elementName]) - 1) number, [elementValue] as value from t2) t2
    pivot(min(value) for letter in ([t], [p], [n])) pvt2
),
amended_values as (
  select
    pvt1.number,
    coalesce(pvt2.t, pvt1.t) as t,
    coalesce(pvt2.p, pvt1.p) as p,
    coalesce(pvt2.n, pvt1.n) as n,
    count(case when pvt1.t = '' and pvt1.p = '' then 1 end) over(order by pvt1.number rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as empty_row_number
  from  
    pivoted_t1 pvt1
    left join pivoted_t2 pvt2 on pvt1.t = pvt2.t and pvt1.p = pvt2.p and pvt1.t <> '' and pvt1.p <> ''
),
added_new_values as (
  select
    a.number,
    coalesce(n.t, a.t) as t,
    coalesce(n.p, a.p) as p,
    coalesce(n.n, a.n) as n
  from
    amended_values a
    left join (
      select number, t, p, n, row_number() over (order by number) as row_number
      from pivoted_t2 t2
      where
        t2.t <> ''
        and t2.p <> ''
        and not exists (select * from pivoted_t1 t1 where t1.t = t2.t and t1.p = t2.p)
    ) n on n.row_number = a.empty_row_number
)
select
  concat([elementName], number) as [elementName],
  [elementValue]
from
  added_new_values
  unpivot ([elementValue] for [elementName] in ([t], [p], [n])) upvt
;
```

Comment: MilkTea, if you select the results from each of the stacked CTEs in this solution, you'll see what GSerg did here and how it all comes together. There's a lot going on, but it's really quite elegant. +1

Comment: This is brilliant!  THANKYOU!